# Spectral family/resolution for $A \otimes 1+ 1 \otimes B$

Tags: functional-analysis, tensor-products, mathematical-physics, spectral-theory, unbounded-operators

Let $A, B$ be  unbounded self-adjoint operators on Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H_1}, \mathcal{H_2}$ with spectra $\sigma(A), \sigma(B)$.
We know that : $\sigma(A \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes B)  = \overline{\sigma(A) +\sigma(B)}$ and $A \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes B$ defines an unbounded self-adjoint operator on $\mathcal{H_1} \otimes \mathcal{H_2}$ (after taking its closure).
By the spectral theorem :
$A = \int_{\sigma(A)} \lambda \,dE_A(\lambda)$; $B = \int_{\sigma(B)}  \lambda\, dE_B(\lambda)$; $A \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes B = \int_{\overline{\sigma(A) +\sigma(B)}} \lambda\, dE_{A \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes B}(\lambda)$.

My question is : do we have $E_{A \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes B} = E_A \otimes E_B$ ? If so, how does one show this, do you have a reference that I could cite ? I guess one would have to state that there exists a common spectral family, then taking the closure of $A \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes B$ would yield integrating over the closure of the spectrum, but it seems touchy so I'm looking for a reference.

Comment: I don't know a precise reference, but the spectral measure $E_{A\otimes 1+1\otimes B}$ is not the product measure of $E_A$ and $E_B$, but rather a kind of convolution defined by $E_{A\otimes 1+1\otimes B}(S)=\int 1_S(\lambda+\mu)\,d(E_A\otimes E_B)(\lambda,\mu)$. It's probably easiest to see using the multiplication operator version of the spectral theorem.

Comment: I have the same kind of intuition that's why I'm looking for somewhere where it is quite detailed. In the kind of convolution you wrote, can't we do some sort of change of variables $\phi : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} $, $(\lambda,\mu) \to \lambda+\mu$ to get an integral over $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: You can do that, but you need the pushforward measure of $E_A\otimes E_B$ under this transformation, and I don't think there's any more explicit way to write it, so I'm not sure if this is helpful.

Comment: I'm going to try it by passing onto quadratic forms to get actual measures and see if it works out

Answer (score 1):

While the approach from the comments using multiplication operators is probably the standard way to go and also easier, I like this approach using the Fourier inversion formula and unitary groups.

Since $(e^{itA}\otimes e^{itB})$ is a strongly continuous group of unitaries, there exists a self-adjoint operator $H$ such that $e^{itA}\otimes e^{itB}=e^{itH}$ by Stone's theorem. If $\xi\in D(A)$ and $\eta\in D(B)$, then
\begin{align*}
\frac 1 t(e^{itA}\otimes e^{itB}(\xi\otimes \eta)-\xi\otimes\eta)&=\frac 1 t(e^{itA}\xi-\xi)\otimes e^{itB}\eta+\frac 1 t\xi\otimes (e^{itB}\eta-\eta)\\
&\to A\xi\otimes \eta+\xi\otimes B\eta.
\end{align*}
Thus $A\odot 1+1\odot B\subset H$, which implies $A\otimes 1+1\otimes B=H$ (you cannot have proper inclusions of self-adjoint operators).

Let $E$ denote the spectral measure of $H$. If $\phi\in\mathcal S(\mathbb R)$ and $\xi\in \mathcal H_1\otimes\mathcal H_2$, then
\begin{align*}
\int \phi(t)\,d\mu_\xi(t)&=\int\hat\phi(t)\,d\check\mu_\xi(t)\\
&=\int\int\hat\phi(t)e^{2\pi it\lambda}\,d\mu_\xi(\lambda)\,dt\\
&=\int\hat\phi(t)\langle\xi,e^{2\pi itH}\xi\rangle\,dt\\
&=\int\hat\phi(t)\langle \xi,e^{2\pi it A}\otimes e^{2\pi it B}\xi\rangle\,dt\\
&=\int\langle\xi,\int\int\hat\phi(t)e^{2\pi i(\lambda+\mu)t}\,d(E_A\otimes E_B)(\lambda,\mu)\xi\rangle\,dt\\
&=\int\int \hat\phi(t)e^{2\pi i(\lambda+\mu)t}\,dt\,d\langle\xi,(E_A\otimes E_B)\xi\rangle(\lambda,\mu)\\
&=\int \phi(\lambda+\mu)\,d\langle\xi,(E_A\otimes E_B)\xi\rangle(\lambda,\mu).
\end{align*}
It follows by approximation that
$$
\mu_\xi(S)=\int 1_S(\lambda+\mu)\,d\langle\xi,(E_A\otimes E_B)\xi\rangle(\lambda,\mu)
$$
for every Borel set $S\subset \mathbb R$.

Comment: No warranty for the correctness of the constants in the Fourier transform, but in these kinds of situations, mistakes often cancel out.

Comment: Thanks a lot that's actually helpful. Following the earlier discussion about the pullback of the projection, I found this (if anyone is wondering), section 2.2 : https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0723086921000244